# Different result when debug and publish ASP.Net MVC

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing website with ASP.Net and get some problem.
The different result when I debug and publish the project. Its like the css and image not synchronized.

Debug Version (IIS Express):
[image]

Publish Version (Using IIS Manager Windows 10):
[image]

I'm using this code:

`<div class="img" style="background-image: url(../../images/png/007-pray.png);"></div>`

the image not showing off. and some edited css not changed in some page. (its like 2 different kind of file that I publish)

Am I missing something when run the web app? 
the solution manager is set to debug version for both debug and publish version.

need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clear the cache and then reload the page, Sometimes, css files or images are browsed through cached memory of browser. Or use `Ctrl + Shift + R` to reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is...

this is the path where I publish my webapp.
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\alumnipmkmaranatha`

when I check path for the image folder, the folder 'alumnipmkmaranatha' is not included.
Then I checked to my IIS Manager: I put 2 web app in default web app.

So if I use 
`<img src="~/ImagesFolder/Imagename.png" />` it goes to 'wwwroot' folder, not 'alumnipmkmaranatha'

Thanks to AbdulHannah

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you can share the Code of these Image elements.

I am assuming that you are specifying the source of image elements as follows

```
<img src="../../ImagesFolder/Imagename.png" />
```

If that's the case I prefer to use the following syntax where the tilted sign specifies the root followed with the remaining path.

```
<img src="~/ImagesFolder/Imagename.png" />
```

if you are using a css for these images then i would prefer to use inline css with following syntax

```
<div class="someclass" style="background-image: url(@Url.Content("~/ImagesFolder/Imagename.png"));"></div>
```

**Important Note:** if all of the above points don't help then make sure that these images are part of the visual studio solution. Sometimes when you publish the images are not included in the folder, the best way to verify such case is to go to the physical directory where you published this project and see the images folder and check if the images exist or not, if not copy them mannually or the better pracrtice is to locate them in Solution explorer in windows right click the image and click on Include to Project option.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think image url or css should be referenced using Tilled sign. Please verify.
2) Could you please check you have all the images in the published file also?

Thanks

Comment: I checked it and all of the images is in the published file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your resources are not copying on the published version, can you please try to select all your images in visual studio directory > right-click > properties > Copy to Output Directory > Copy always. and then publish your project.

Please check the attached image for reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFxBr.png